# gcloud ai-platform local train not running in jupyter notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, gcloud, gcp-ai-platform-training

This one unsolved part from another post. I am trying to submit a google cloud job that trains cnn model for mnist digit.

here's my systems. windows 10, anaconda, jupyter notebook 6, python 3.6, tf 1.13.0.

I use gcloud command for local train. the second cell seems stuck at [*] status and showing nothing until I close and halt the ipynb file. the training started right after it and results are correct as I monitored it on Tensorboard.

I can make it run in a terminal without this issue. I also successfully submitted the job to cloud and finished successfully.

any thought of the local train problem? codes are here.

```
OUTDIR='trained_test'

INPDIR='..\data'
shutil.rmtree(path = OUTDIR, ignore_errors = True)
```

```
!gcloud ai-platform local train \
    --module-name=trainer.task \
    --package-path=trainer \
    -- \
    --output_dir=$OUTDIR \
    --input_dir=$INPDIR \
    --epochs=2 \
    --learning_rate=0.001 \
    --batch_size=100
```

Comment: Try to split your Python cell and your Bash cell.

Comment: they were split and didn't work. I edited the post to make it clear.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have windows system. I can't test and help more :(

Comment: I also tried local predict, and cloud predict. local predict wasn't working either. cloud predict works well. it seems to be some conflict between python 2.7 and windows gcloud sdk for the predict case.

Comment: Python and Windows aren't the best friends. Colleagues also have issues with gcloud and python2.7.

Comment: despite of the mystery of the local train and predict, cloud train and online predict work well. why is gcloud  not 3x  yet?

Comment: Good question for Googlers.... Same remarks for Dataflow/Beam Python lib, only available in python 2.....

Comment: I found this page about How to use Jupyter on a Google Cloud VM https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-jupyter-on-a-google-cloud-vm-5ba1b473f4c2 that seems to be useful.

Comment: yes. it's informative. however, Lak's platform is on gcp. His coursera course uses datalab which is very convenient though. I currently use windows on my local machine.